# How to read comma separated data set using scanf_s - C Programming

Tags: c, scanf

I don't have a working code I can share right now, but basically what I am trying to achieve is to read a user input or from a file in the following format:

```
1,2
2,5
3,4
4,5
etc...
```

or

1,3 4,5 6,7 8,6 ...
So a comma separated pair of real numbers and I would need to assign them to an array or 2d array and calculate their means, median, mode etc...

I tried `scanf_s("%d,",&n)` and stuff like that but none of them have worked out so far. I am really new to C and came from Java so everything been very confusing. If any tips or just an example would be greatly appreciated. I know you can also use fgets, gets or sscanf, however I have not learned those yet.

This was a code sent by another user:(but i don't really understand it, because it gave me src could be 0 error)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( void )
{
  char *src = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
  fgets(src, 500, stdin);
  int arr[500];
  int index = 0;
  int n;

  while ( sscanf ( src, "%d,%n", &arr[index], &n ) == 1 ) {  
    printf("%d\n", arr[index]);
    index++;
    src += n;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That should work for the first number on each line. You can't use it for the second number since there's no `,` after it.

Comment: Post what you tried. We don't expect it to be working code, since you're looking for help getting it to work.

Comment: "a comma separated pair of real numbers" --> after reading the line into a string, use `int x,y; sscanf ( src, "%d ,%d", &x, &y )`

Comment: So reading the line into a string, I am assuming that's what "src" is? would just be a normal scanf_s("%s", &src)?

Comment: Note that you have an incipient memory leak — you `malloc()` space for `src` (which seems a bit pointless; it could perfectly well be a simple array) and then increments `src` willy-nilly so that there is no way to `free()`, or reuse it if you want to read more than one line of data.  I used `char data[500]; char *src = data;` to avoid the memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
scanf_s("%d,%d", &n1, &n2);
```

to read both numbers on each line at once. You can't use `%d,` for the second number, because there's no comma after it.

`scanf()` returns the number of inputs that were processed. Since you're reading two numbers at once, you should check that it returns `2`, not `1`.

```
int n1, n2;
while (scanf("%d , %d", &n1, &n2) == 2 ) { 
    printf("first number = %d, second number = %d\n", n1, n2);
}
```

Comment: so for your alternate, do I have to put that through a loop? I will give that a try. Thanks, because I am thinking of using an array and looping through it. So I am guessing I have to make a while loop and have user keep entering data until they press a none number character or EOL

Comment: Whatever you do is going to be in a loop to read all the lines.

Comment: What does the %n do? I know %d is for specifying integers. And what is sscanf? That is what threw me off from the previous code and when I run it it always say "use scanf_s instead" warning. I understand what the idea is. but kinda confused on the way C handles things. And would that work for both format I mentioned in the question (while(sscanf...)), like if I enter a whitespace or a newline character would that automatically read the next line?

Comment: I meant to change the `scanf()`. `sscanf()` is for reading from the string that was read with `fgets()`. `%n` is for getting the number of characters that have been read so far, which allows starting from the current place in the string each time. Neither of them is relevant to your question, I fixed it.

Comment: I've added spaces to the format string, that will automatically skip over whitespace.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. Really appreciate your time. I will try these once i get home from class!

Answer (score 0):

If the input format may **really** vary (your question is not very certain about it), `strtod()` is your main weapon.

```
char *P = MyLine, *NewP;   //MyLine is the input line
double Val[2];
do {
  Val[0]=strtod(P, &NewP);  //It reads the first value and shifts the pointer.
  if (NewP==P) return ERROR_EMPTY_STRING; //No values found! Sometimes maybe OK, if empty lines are allowed.
  P=NewP;
  while (*P == ' ') P++; //Omitting empty space between first value and comma.
  if (*P!=',') return ERROR_WRONG_FORMAT; //Wrong input: no comma between the values!
  Val[1]=strtod(P, &NewP);  //It reads the second value and shifts the pointer.
  if (NewP==P) return ERROR_WRONG_FORMAT; //No second value found! This is definitely not OK.
  P=NewP;
  while (*P == ' ') P++; //Omitting probable trailing spaces (we don't need it for strtod() because it does it by itself, but we need it for the endline check);
  ProcessSomehow(Val);   //Process the pair
} while (*P && *P != '\r' && *P != '\n' );
return LINE_ENDED_OK;
```

This code will parse

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

as well as

```
1,2 3,4 5,6
7,8 9,10 11,12
```

or even this

```
 2, 4 1 , 5 6 ,8
1,3 4, 4
1,4 6 ,4    6, 8   2,7  2, 12  4, 8
```

everything as long as they are comma-separated pairs and every pair is separated by at least one space. You can also easily modify it to allow `1,2; 4, 3; 2, 3  7, 2` or any other additional separators.

`#define` error codes according to your own taste (or use any other error handling, if you want to).

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to read the line in the first place.

Comment: The question says he doesn't want to use `fgets()` because he hasn't learned that yet.

Comment: is there a way to do it with scanf? or something similar? Can you give an example with the getline? (MyLine = getLine(...)? )

Comment: https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112  ```size_t MyLineSize = 128; char *MyLine = (char *)malloc(MyLineSize * sizeof(char)); getline(&MyLine,&MyLineSize,stdin);```   ```scanf (%s...``` splits the input by spaces, it's not very good for this. Also use ```fgets()``` if you learned it, I was wrong (it's OK too).

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two main solutions.  One is to continue to read numbers singly, so you really aren't too bothered by whether there are commas are present or not; the other is to read the numbers in pairs.

Option A involves a minor tweak to the format string from `"%d,%n"` to `"%d %n"` so you find out where the number ends (more precisely, where the first character that's not white space appears after the number), and skip the comma separately in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[500];
    char *src = data;
    fgets(src, 500, stdin);
    int arr[500];
    int index = 0;
    int n;

    while (sscanf(src, "%d %n", &arr[index], &n) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[index++]);
        src += n;
        if (*src == ',')
        {
            putchar('=');
            src++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `putchar('=')` lets me see when the comma is skipped; it wouldn't be present in 'production' code.

Sample output (Bash [Here String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) notation):

```
$ read41 <<< '1,2  3,4   5,6   7, 8   9,10, 11 , 12xyz'
1
=2
3
=4
5
=6
7
=8
9
=10
=11
=12
$
```

Be cautious — a trailing blank in a `scanf()` format is devasting for interactive input, but harmless for `sscanf()`.  Note that there is a stray comma after `10` in the data, but this version of the code doesn't care about that.  It also doesn't care about where newlines appear in pairs (or it wouldn't if it iterated on `while (fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin) != 0) { char *src = data; … }`).

Option B involves reading numbers in pairs.  Since you're using `sscanf()` in a loop, you still need the `%n` conversion specification.  The second space in the format string (after the comma) isn't strictly necessary (the `%d` will skip white space too), but it is harmless and symmetric.  This demands that there is one comma between pairs of numbers which must be on the same line (but allows spaces, or no spaces, around the comma), and pairs must appear on the same line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[500];
    int arr[500];
    int index = 0;

    while (fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int n;
        char *src = data;
        while (sscanf(src, "%d , %d %n", &arr[index + 0], &arr[index + 1], &n) == 2)
        {
            printf("(%d,%d)\n", arr[index + 0], arr[index + 1]);
            src += n;
            index += 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (using Bash [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) too):

```
$ read43 <<< $'1,2  3,4   5,6   7,8\n9,10 11 , 12xyz'
(1,2)
(3,4)
(5,6)
(7,8)
(9,10)
(11,12)
$
```